# Why am I getting an unchecked cast warning?

Tags: java

In a JTree I use this code and  I don't receive any warnings:

```
Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en = (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>)selNode.postorderEnumeration();
```

but when I use the following code I get an `unchecked cast` warning:

```
Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en = (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>)selNode.pathFromAncestorEnumeration( this.getRootNode() );
```

Whats the deal?

Comment: What are the return types of those methods?

Comment: [Both](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#preorderEnumeration()) return an [Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)

Comment: `getRootNode()` just returns a [DefaultMutableTreeNode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html#preorderEnumeration())

Comment: The links I provided are to the Java 1.4.2 API, but my Java version is  1.6.33... 1.4.2 is just the one that always pops up first in a Google search.

Comment: @typoknig What's the type for `this.getRootNode()` ?

Comment: @user1420750 read two comments above :)

Comment: @typoknig I wonder if that's because the signature for the method is `pathFromAncestorEnumeration(TreeNode ancestor)` whereas you are passing it the DefaultMutableTreeNode. Why don't you try to cast `this.getRootNode()` to TreeNode?

Comment: @user1420750 Just tried, no go. Good thought though.

Answer (score 6):

It's basically due to generic type erasure. At execution time, the object will only know it's an `Enumeration<E>` for some type `E` - so it can't *actually* check that it's an `Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>`.

See the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) for more information, particularly the [type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#What%20is%20type%20erasure?) entry.

EDIT: I don't know why the first would succeed without a warning and the second not. I'd expect *both* to give warnings. You really *can't* always get away without `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` in my experience - it's worth minimizing it where you can, but it's an unfortunate fact of life with Java generics :(

EDIT: I actually get a warning from *both* of these:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = null;

        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en1 = 
            (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>)node.postorderEnumeration();
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en2 = 
            (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>)node.pathFromAncestorEnumeration(null);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>javac -Xlint Test.java
Test.java:8: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en1 = (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTre
eNode>)node.postorderEnumeration();

                                ^
  required: Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>
  found:    Enumeration
Test.java:9: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode> en2 = (Enumeration<DefaultMutableTre
eNode>)node.pathFromAncestorEnumeration(null);

                                       ^
  required: Enumeration<DefaultMutableTreeNode>
  found:    Enumeration
2 warnings
```

Comment: But why is he getting a cast warning only in the second case? Both APIs of `DefaultMutableTreeNode` return `Enumeration` and not `Enumeration<E>`?

Comment: The only suspicious thing is the absence of a warning in the first case. Both lines **should** produce that warning if the linked Javadoc is the relevant one. That API is not even aware of Generics so all casts are from raw types into parameterized ones. However, OP linked to a J2SE 1.4 version so the Javadoc may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is my question too.  I have been told that you should never need `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, and I believe I wrote the code in my question so that annotation should not be needed.

Comment: @typoknig: See my edit - I'm getting a warning on both calls. Can you provide a similar short but complete program which only shows a warning on the second call?